# Go ioutil using too many file descriptors/leak?

Tags: go, file-io, unmarshalling, ulimit, defer-keyword

I am going through a list of files and Unmarshalling the xml data in them into an array of structs `rArray`. I intend to process about 18000 files. When I get to about 1300 files processed, the program panics and says that too many files are open. If I limit the amount of files processed to a safe amount of 1000, the program does not crash.

<s>As seen below, I am using `ioutil.ReadFile` to read the file data.</s>

```
for _, f := range files {

    func() {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./" + recordDir + "/" + f.Name())
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("error reading %v", err)
            return
        } else {
            if (strings.Contains(filepath.Ext(f.Name()), "xml")) {

                //unmarshal data and put into struct array
                err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &rArray[a])
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("error decoding %v: %v",f.Name(), err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

I am not sure if Go is using too many file descriptors or not closing the files fast enough.

After reading https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/7yXXjgcOikM and viewing the `ioutil` source in http://golang.org/src/pkg/io/ioutil/ioutil.go, the code for `ioutil.ReadFile` shows that it uses `defer` to close the file. `defer` runs when calling function is returned and `ReadFile()` is the calling function. Am I correct in this understanding?
I also tried wrapping the `ioutil.ReadFile` part of my code in a function, but it makes no difference.

My `ulimit` is set to unlimited.

**UPDATE:** 
I believe that the error of too many files is actually occurring during my Unzip function.

```
func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    for _, f := range r.File {
        rc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(path, f.Mode())
        } else {
            f, err := os.OpenFile(
                path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }

            _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
            if err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
            f.Close()
        }
        rc.Close()
    }
    r.Close()
    return nil
}
```

I initially got the `Unzip` function from https://gist.github.com/hnaohiro/4572580, but upon further inspection, the use of `defer` in the gist author's function seemed wrong as the file would only be closed after the `Unzip()` function returned which is too late becuase then 18000 file descriptors will be open. ;)

<s>I replaced the deferred `Close`s with explicit `Close()` as shown above, but am still getting the same "too many open files" error. Is there a problem with my modified Unzip function?</s>

**UPDATE # 2**
Oops, I was running this on Heroku and was pushing to the wrong app with my changes this entire time. Lesson learned: verify target app in heroku toolbelt.

Unzip code from https://gist.github.com/hnaohiro/4572580 does **not** work as it does not close files until all files processed.

My unzip code with explicit close above works and so does the defer version in @peterSO's answer.

Comment: That's weird, what version of go (`go version`)? also does replacing `ioutil.ReadFile` with `f, err := os.Open(....)` / `defer f.Close()` / `ioutil.ReadAll` help?

Comment: @OneOfOne, I narrowed the cause down to another function I had, but am still having problems as described in update above. I am currently using go 1.2.2. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps take a look in `/proc/$pid/fd` to see what files are open in the app (it should contain symlinks representing each open file descriptor).  That might give an indication of which descriptors are being leaked.

Comment: Are you using go routines for each file by any chance?

Comment: Yes I think the problem is with too many goroutines opening the file and yield to the scheduler. What is the code logic ?

Comment: @OneOfOne, I am not using any go routines for each file. The code should process each file one by one, but I believe that I have found a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would modify the Unzip function from https://gist.github.com/hnaohiro/4572580 to the following:

```
package main

import (
    "archive/zip"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
)

func unzipFile(f *zip.File, dest string) error {
    rc, err := f.Open()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rc.Close()

    path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
    if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
        err := os.MkdirAll(path, f.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    } else {
        f, err := os.OpenFile(
            path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer f.Close()

        _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Close()

    for _, f := range r.File {
        err := unzipFile(f, dest)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := Unzip("./sample.zip", "./out")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, this works (as well as my explicit version from before), but could you please explain why the `unzipFile` method doesn't keep N file descriptors open? I thought that the `defer`s in `unzipFile` will only run when unzipFile returns? I am interested it this. Thanks!

Comment: very nice separation of unzipFile - it ensures each file will get closed quickly.